# Sifting property of a Dirac delta Mellin inverse transformation

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta, mellin-transform

Using the Dirac delta function $$f(t) = \delta(t-a)$$
to get the Mellin inverse transformation $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} e^{-sa}e^{st} ds$$

From there I made those changes. $s = iw$ and $ds = idw$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iwa}e^{iwt} ds = f(t) = \delta(t-a)$$

However, I don't see how to use the sifting property to solve this integral since the sifting property says
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) dx = f(0)$$

I'm wondering if I can verify the sifting property using $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(a) \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iwa}e^{iwt} ds =  f(0)$$ where $f(a) = e^{-sa}$, thus $f(0) = 1$

Comment: You might use the representation $\int e^{i s t} dt = 2 \pi \delta(s)$

Comment: Might be more coherent to being as "the inverse Mellin transform of $\delta(t-a)$ is" (and then the second display)...

Comment: @kevinkayaks does it makes sense that $f(a) = e^{-sa}$